# Error using Twitter with Golang

Tags: twitter, go

I'm developing a web application with golang and using an API of Twitter to do the login. It runs very well in my computer but I have that error when I put it in production.

```
Error getting request token, Post http://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token: Call error 3: invalid security ticket
```

Comment: Are you sure, that Consumer Secret, Consumer Key and Callback URL are correct? Invalid Callback URL is the most common problem.

Comment: Please post your sample code.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to tell without seeing the code, but I'd bet that your credentials are incorrect.

I'd recommend using a client library to handle your authentication to make debugging easier. (Here's [a Go twitter client library I wrote](https://github.com/ChimeraCoder/anaconda)).

If the error is that you're not creating the correct query, using a well-tested library will fix that. If you still get the same error, check that all of your credentials (including the callback URL!) are correct.